# Search Method on a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap

I need to print the details of the employee that the user inputs.  So far all I can get is the name.  Can anyone give me a hand with this?

**EmployeeStore**

```
public void add(Employee employee)
{       
    map.put(employee.getEmployeeName(), employee);
}

public Employee searchByName(String name) 
{
    System.out.println(name);
    return map.get(name);    
}
```

---

**Usage**

```
EmployeeStore Store = new EmployeeStore();
Store.add(new Employee ("James O' Carroll", 18,"hotmail.com"));
Store.add(new Employee ("Andy Carroll", 1171,"yahoo.com"));
Store.add(new Employee ("Luis Suarez", 7,"gmail.com"));
Store.searchByName("James O' Carroll");
```

Comment: how does the `add` method of `EmployeeStore` look like?

Comment: You get an Employee back from searchByName, what's the problem?

Comment: and how do you define the hashmap? `Map<String,Employee> map = new HashMap<>()`?

Comment: This just doesn't make any sense... Like NathanHughes said: you get an `Employee` back from the method. Just call whatever methods you have on that object to print it...

Comment: How is Employee's `toString()` defined?

Comment: @Pendo826 be sure to "accept" an answer when you find an acceptable one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the key, not the value stored at the key.

```
public Employee searchByName(String name) 
{
    Employee employee = map.get(name);    
    System.out.println(employee.toString());
    return employee;
}
```

Assuming the Employer class has defined a toString() method.